# Expecting null in Scala. Should Option be used?

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a play template in which the most typical scenario for a parameter is "null".
I have understood that idiomatic Scala favors Option instead.
My first intuition coming from java would be using null.

Case with null:
In Controller

```
views.html.addPost(errors.errorsAsJson)
```

In View

```
@(errors: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = null) 
...
@if(errors != null){@errors}
```

Case with Option:
In Controller

```
views.html.addPost(Option(errors.errorsAsJson))
```

In View

```
@(errors: Option[play.api.libs.json.JsValue] = None)
...
@{errors match {
      case None => {}
      case _ => {errors.get}
    }
}
```

**Update:** I got it now.
Instead of:

```
@{errors match {
    case None => {}
    case _ => {errors.get}
 }
}
```

I could just do

```
@errors
```

**Update 2:**
Apparently I didn't have to do the null check with null either? Maybe some`Play framework` magic? Calling a null variable worked without exception.

Comment: The key reason to use Option is that using it everywhere turns runtime NullPointerExceptions caused by the programmer not realising (or just forgetting) that a method might not always return a valid value of its documented return type into compile time errors, which then prompts you to immediately go fix the problem at the right location (even if that fix is just adding `.get` to declare "yes, I want this code to crash at runtime if this is `None`"). Even if it takes a little more typing (though it doesn't have to be as bad as your examples, as shown in dhg's answer), that's still a gain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason `Option` is less verbose is that you don't need to do those null checks.  In other words, your `match/case` verbosity is unnecessary.

Let's assume we have these two variables:

```
val x: Option[Int] = Some(5)
val y: Option[Int] = None
```

If we want to call a function things that are `Some` rather than `None`, we don't need to null-check:

```
x foreach println  // prints 5
y foreach println  // nothing printed
```

Or if we want to apply a function and get a new result, it's similar, and keeps track of whether the input was present or not.

```
val f = (i: Int) => i + 1
x map f  // Some(6)
y map f  // None
```

There are plenty more examples of how `Option` cleans things up, but this should give you an idea.

Comment: Cool, thanks that really worked. Just tested and @errors without the pattern matching.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out `getOrElse` specifically here, since it's the most literal substitute for the `match`.

Comment: Here is a very handy link: http://blog.tmorris.net/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/. It helps in shortening a lot of pattern matching scenarios for Option. It helped me a LOT when I was first learning scala.